# Suckless's simple terminal non-monospace fonts

Tags: font-awesome, x-st

I am trying to make non-monospace fonts work in Suckless's simple terminal. I have an issue with FontAwesome larger glyphs (e.g. with [battery glyphs](https://fontawesome.com/icons/battery-three-quarters?style=solid) being overlapped by other characters.

I have tried to apply the [font2 patch](https://st.suckless.org/patches/font2/) to add FontAwesome as fallback font, it did not improve the situation.

```c
static char *font2[] = {
    "FontAwesome:pixelsize=11:antialias=true:autohint=true" 
    //FontAwesome as font name works in other programs (such as i3blocks)
};

// Note: I have applied the complete patch, not only these lines.
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You got the names wrong.

```c
static char *font2[] = {
    "Font Awesome 5 Free:pixelsize=11:antialias=true:autohint=true",
    "Font Awesome 5 Brands:pixelsize=11:antialias=true:autohint=true",
};
```